# Theres a way to loop on slim a html element?

Tags: html, ruby, loops, slim-lang

I'd like to loop this on slim:

```
.row.vh14.sand_bg.relative
  .col-lg-6.col-lg-offset-3.fill_top_60px
    .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
    .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
    .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
    .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
    .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
    .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
```

but no one by one, something like less loops o similar way,just define the number of iteration neededa and voila.

something:

element x (5) = 
                element
                element
                element
                element
                element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
- 5.times do
   .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop you can do it as below example.

```
.row.vh14.sand_bg.relative
  .col-lg-6.col-lg-offset-3.fill_top_60px
   - for item in (1..6) # you can define your range how many times you want to loop 
    .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
```

---

## UPDATED

I think slim indentation is causing problem..

```
 .row.vh14.sand_bg.relative
   .col-lg-6.col-lg-offset-3.fill_top_60px
     - for item in (1..6) # you can define your range how many times you want to loop 
        .trabajo.col-lg-4.test_img.vh5
```

Comment: This worked. -5.times do |n|
  class> class="div#{n}"